# Recursive pseudocode on finding the occurences of a character

Tags: algorithm, recursion

If the string`s  characters are put in an array, how can you find the number of occurences of a specific character, using recursion? 
im going with this pseudocode for now:

```
f(A[0;n-1],k)
if(n=0)then return;
c=0;
if(A[n-1]=k)then c++;`
return c+f(A[0;n-2],k)
```

Comment: Why would you want to use recursion? I bet its slower and more memory consuming than using a loop.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You are right, but it is specifically asked to be done with recursion

Comment: What is the problem? The idea of the pseudocode looks good to me. Implement it and run some test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the recursive function f(S, c) where S is the input string.
We can formulate f(S, c) as:

```
Base case: 
f(S, c) = 0, if length(S) == 0

General case:
f(S, c) = 1 + f(S[1:], c), if S[0] == c
        = f(S[1:], c), otherwise
where S[x:] denotes substring of S starting at xth index till the end.
```

In words we could think of it as: Suppose we know the answer to the smaller subproblem which is the substring starting from index 1 and ending at last character. Now if the 0th character matches the given string, our answer will simply be 1 + answer to the smaller subproblem, otherwise our answer will be the answer of the smaller subproblem

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a sort of recursion problem, there must be a base case. It is end of string character or `0` situation for its length. Having determined the base case, now we walk through on the string. We start walking, if there is the character wanted to be found, we send `+1` to next recursion call. In every call, the `+1` is returned to other recursion until the base is hit.